ESP32 monitoring highpower LEDs
I’d like some help with a small project I’m working on. I want to use an ESP32 to do two things:
-control dozens of HIGH POWER LEDs of this type: XLamp® XM LEDs Archives - Cree LED so that I can turn them on and off whenever I want
-from a digital camera, activate the latter’s triggering for each LED when it’s ON.
However, I’m not entirely sure what I need to connect my LEDs to, so I imagine I’ll need an external source to power them. I’ve thought of using a BUCK-style converter for my non-isolated power supply, but it’s still all a bit hazy for me: how do I connect my ESP in all this, and what type of converter do I need? Should my LEDs be in series or parallel? Which mosfet should I choose, and do I need one for all my LEDs?
I’ve read about similar projects that used components such as a WS2811, but I don’t think it’s really necessary here. I’m a bit rusty on electronics, but I’d like your opinion.

Depending on the power you need, it may be simpler to use a controllable constant current LED power supply (Meanwell makes a ton of them). If you only need one color of LED and you're not going to control them individually, then it's the simplest solution and it'll cost the same as the power supply you would need anyway. However if you want to control each LED separately or you use multiple colors then controlling the power supply won't work. Can you give info about number of LEDs, power per LED (voltage,current)? Do you plan to use two color temperatures or one?

Control each LED individually or all of them at once? Also does it need to be on continuously or just a few seconds? (that's for calculating the heat sink) Is this for photo or video? Do you need it silent or can you tolerate a fan? Does it need to synchronize with the camera's flash trigger (this sets a minimum reaction time for the power supply) or just manual turn on/off? Basically, every detail you can.

How quickly does the LED need to reach full brightness? Is a 1 second delay ok? 1ms? Lots of drivers you could connect to your controller, but they may not respond instantly to signals like a flash would.
